# WPF Border and Header alignment

Tags: wpf, listbox, alignment, border, itemtemplate

Got two problems here in my XAML code.

```
<Grid Margin="20">

        <ListBox x:Name="lbChampToSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding Lst}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Border Background="FloralWhite" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">                
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Grid Margin="5,2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0">Libellé</Label>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>                    
            </ListBox.Template>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5,2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition  Width="100" SharedSizeGroup="Col1"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Libelle }" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </Border>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

First : whatever I try, I cannot align the header and the columns containing  checkboxes (with a text labelling the checkbox it's worth). At the end, the header checkbox is supposed to check all the subsequents.

Second : I simply try to have a border on my entire listbox including the header but I got a xaml error saying the member Template is not accessible or does not exists.

Thx for your answers.

Comment: Can you put header outside ListBox?

Comment: @Anime Nope, does not work either... apparently it's good use to manage header inside the control itself, but I could be wrong ! Thx for you comment.

Comment: I think you need a ListView instead of ListBox

Comment: Could you use ListView instead of ListBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otherwise, by using a ListView you can have header for items :

```
<ListView Margin="10" x:Name="lbChampToSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding Lst}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" BorderBrush="Silver"
                 BorderThickness="1">
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Libelle" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Libelle}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{ Binding IsChecked}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <CheckBox/>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Looks better thx Anime, but I still have an offset between the header checkbox and the checboxes in the column.

Comment: @Anime Perfect, thx a lot ! I've learned a lot on controls with that answer.

Comment: @Anime what about aligning all the contents on the left ? Both content of the header and the columns, in a word, all the `ListView` items aligned on the left ?

Comment: Replace ListView.Resource by this <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>

Comment: and you can put margin for headers if you want. ex : <CheckBox Margin="4 0 0 0"/>

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the second question:

Your Border should be within the ControlTemplate (given I have guessed right how you want it to be).

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border Background="FloralWhite" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">
```

Now on to the first question: There are many things that affect the layouting of the items in the ListBox. Here's the method I would use to solve the problem.

1. Remove margins from your Grids, I would set them to 0, at least for now. You can add layouting later, when you know what affects what.
2. Download [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)
3. Start your application and start snooping it
4. Find your controls in the hierarchy, and try modifying the margin/padding values. That way you'll see what affects layouting.
5. Apply new values in code.

Comment: Thx, I'll try snoop !